# Is there a maximum storage for Google chrome internet browsing history?

Tags: windows-10

My internet history is gradually disappearing from the earliest dates after about 3 months. Does my browsing history have a maximum amount or time of storage?
I don't know where to go to research.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome stores history for 90 days only. You can find it here
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589

> **What your history page shows**
>
> Your History page shows the webpages you've visited on Chrome in the ***last 90 days***. It doesn’t store Chrome pages you’ve visited like chrome://settings, pages you've visited in Incognito mode, or pages you've already deleted from your browsing history.